# Blender 3D character model Rain render problems

Tags: rendering

I downloaded the Rain V2 character from blender studio. I am new to Blender and trying to understand a few things. When I try to render the character I get this issue shown in the image (highlighted with black). What could be the issue and how can I fix this? I am using Blender 3.5. I have not changed anything just added the camera and area lights. [image]

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)